# How to repeat variables in Visual Studio Snippet

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to type the property name once for this snippet and have it fill in all three place holders. When I currently try this with Visual Studio, it only fills in the first variable. Is there a way to fill all three in by typing the name once?

```
  <div class="input-container clearfix">
            <div class="input-row clearfix">
                <div class="bp2-wdn-col-one-fourth input-title">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.$PropertyName$, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                </div>
                <div class="bp2-wdn-col-three-fourths">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.$PropertyName$, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.$PropertyName$, "", new { @class = "" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And that property is defined above like

```
  <Declarations>
  <Literal>
    <ID>PropertyName</ID>
    <ToolTip>Name of the model property</ToolTip>
    <Default>Property</Default>
  </Literal>
</Declarations>
```

Is there a way to fill all three in by typing the name once?

Answer (score 0):

The key (hack?) here is to set `Default` to be the same as your `ID`. Here is an example that generates async relay command based on Windows Community Toolkit. Works for me in VS2022:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>Async Command based on Windows Community Toolkit</Title>
      <Author>
      </Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>wcmda</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Name</ID>
          <ToolTip>Name of the command</ToolTip>
          <Default>Name</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Method</ID>
          <ToolTip>The method that is to be called asynchronously</ToolTip>
          <Default>Method</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[#region $Name$AsyncCommand
private AsyncRelayCommand _$Name$AsyncCommand;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public AsyncRelayCommand $Name$AsyncCommand => _$Name$AsyncCommand ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(async () =>
{
    await $Method$
},
() => true);
#endregion]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save it into your snippets folder (normally in your `Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets` folder), then start VS2022 and type `wcmda` in a CS file and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. It will generate the command and select the first occurrance of `Name`. Type your command name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. This will replace all occurrances of `Name` in the command and take you to `Method`.